# Create a forest plot for weighted mean effect size for each study in meta-analysis

Tags: r, r-forestplot

I am conducting a meta-analysis using the robust variance estimation (RVE) technique due to the fact that each study contains multiple effect sizes. In my case, effect sizes are r (linear association). 
After extensive online research, I decided to use **robumeta** package in **R**, and **robu** function to calculate the overall effect size across all studies. Below is my main model and data structure in R.

```
`run.average <- robu(formula = Correlation ~ 1,
          var.eff.size = Varience, 
          data = d2, 
          studynum = ID, 
          modelweights = "CORR")`
```

[image: This is how my data looks like in R]

My goal is to create a **forest plot** to display the weighted mean effect size for **each study** (so, each study only has 1 effect size).

As far as I know, **forest.robu()** can plot each effect size, which, however, is not what I need. Using other functions like **forest()** may not apply to RVE model.

Therefore, I wonder if there is any solution to creating a forest plot for weighted mean effect size for each study.

Comment: Resurrecting this in the hope you found an answer @Jessica Luo!